# Should I use silicone or caulk between skirting board and vinyl tiles, cement and vinyl tiles?

Tags: vinyl-flooring, caulk, gap, silicone

Should I use silicone between vinyl tiles and wooden skirting?  I imagine yes since the skirting board may contract even though the tiles do not?

What about if there is no skirting i.e. vinyl and cement/brick, in this case do I use silicone, caulk or either is ok?

Thanks

Comment: What room is this and why would you need to caulk?

Comment: @PlatinumGoose kitchen.  Part of it has a skirting board part of it doesn't.  I was under the impression silicone is for expandable things like skirting board whereas caulk is for non expendable like wall and vinyl?

Comment: If it's for the skirting board I don't think you need it unless for appearance. Maybe a picture of the area might help.